# Parsing a JSON with dl4j RecordReader

Tags: dl4j

I plan to use dl4j on a dataset which is in the following format:

> {"articles": [{"abstractText":"text..", "journal":"journal..", "meshMajor":["mesh1",...,"meshN"],
>   "pmid":"PMID", "title":"title..", "year":"YYYY"},..., {..}]}

The field meshMajor contains the class labels and the rest are the input for the model. The input features are textual data.

I was wondering if there are any built in JSON dataset iterators like the CSV one. I looked up in the examples posted on github but couldn't locate one. If there isn't one available, can someone please provide some pointers on implementing it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had asked this Q in DL4J's gitter and the solution is using Jackson record reader. Additional details are available https://github.com/deeplearning4j/DataVec/tree/master/datavec-api/src/main/java/org/datavec/api/records/reader/impl/jackson and example of reading JSON is available at

1. https://github.com/deeplearning4j/DataVec/blob/master/datavec-api/src/test/java/org/datavec/api/records/reader/impl/JacksonLineRecordReaderTest.java and,
2. https://github.com/deeplearning4j/DataVec/blob/master/datavec-api/src/test/java/org/datavec/api/records/reader/impl/JacksonRecordReaderTest.java

Note that there is a difference between JacksonLineRecordReader and JacksonRecordReaderTest.java where the former requires each JSON record to span exactly one line and the latter requiring one file for each JSON record.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a promising start:

https://deeplearning4j.org/docs/latest/datavec-serialization

You should then be able to use the examples here:

https://github.com/deeplearning4j/dl4j-examples/tree/master/datavec-examples/src/main/java/org/datavec/transform/basic